# How can i make the value of one serializer field be dependent on the value of another within the same serializer class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following serializer class

```
    menuitem = MenuItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    menuitem_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()
    unit_price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['user', 'menuitem', 'menuitem_id', 'quantity', 'unit_price', 'price']
        depth = 1

    def get_unit_price(self, obj):
        return obj.menuitem.price

    def get_total_price(self, obj):
        return obj.unit_price * obj.quantity
```

but need to change `quantity` to `menuitem.quantity` and `price` to `quantity * menuitem.price` (`menuitem` being a foreign field)

I used the class methods to return `@property` from the `model` class, but I can't figure out how to save to the database.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('menuitem', 'user')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}, {self.menuitem}, {self.quantity}, {self.price}'
    
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.menuitem.price
    
    @property
    def _unit_price(self):
        return self.menuitem.price
```

But this implementation doesn't save to database although it serialized

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly are you trying to save?